# Will ng-include download all the included HTMLs or pre-compile into a single HTML

Tags: javascript, angularjs

From a performance POV, does using ng-include Angular directive cause included HTMLs to be downloaded to the user's browsers as its own file?

I am not using node server to serve the HTML files, I'm using a CDN like AWS CloudFront.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AngularJS is an entirely client side framework so, yes, it will download each template and it won't pre-compile anything.

You may want to include something like [gulp-ng-templates](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-ng-templates) as part of your client-side build process. This will generate a single js file that will preload all your templates into the template cache, using their natural URL (so your other code doesn't need to change)

Answer (score 1):

`ng-include` will download the template on request. So, if you use `ng-include` to include 3 templates, that means 3 ajax request.

However, you can include the template inside your `index.html` as a script using type equals `text/ng-template`

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="my-tpl.html">
  Content of the template.
</script>
```

Then:

```
<div ng-include="my-tpl.php"></div>
```

This way you will have all the templates inside one file.